# Как последовательно запустить несколько процессов, а код завершения последнего потомка передать первому процессу?

Tags: c, linux

Добрый вечер. Подскажите как правильно выполнить задачу?
Необходимо создать цепочку из 5 последовательно запущенных процессов, когда каждый дочерний процесс становится родителем для следующего потомка. Код завершения последнего потомка передать первому процессу. В первом процессе вывести данное число на экран.

Создал в цикле 5 процессов:

```
pid_t return_value;

  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    return_value = fork();
    printf("%s %d %s %d\n", "Процесс: ", getpid(), "PID: ", return_value);  
  }

  return 0;
```

Данный код выдает мне в терминале огромную простыню, 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю что это из-за того, что после создания нового процесса они продолжают выполняться параллельно. Как код завершения последнего потомка передать первому процессу так и не выяснил. Подскажите как правильно сделать?

Comment: А что означает «последовательно запущенных»? Это в смысле pipe? Или просто каждый процесс запускает следующий, а сам умирает?

Comment: И да, 5 раз fork создаст вам 32 процесса, а не 5.

Comment: pipe не подходит. Нужна именно цепочка процессов

Comment: Почему же pipe не подходит? В родителе (перед fork()) открываете pipe и записываете в переменную 5. Каждый процесс, естественно, наследует эту переменную и pipe. Каждый новый процесс уменьшает эту переменную и запускает новый. Процесс, который после уменьшения переменной получает 0 пишет свой pid в pipe, а новый не запускает. Родитель висит на read. / Сами напишите или черкануть решение в ответе?

Comment: @avp: Можно по идее и без pipe, пусть просто каждый процесс в цепочке передаёт `WEXITSTATUS` потомка назад.

Comment: @avp можно решение?

Comment: @VlaD А как передать WEXITSTATUS потомка назад?

Comment: @LANSELOT: Дождаться завершения потомка и вернуть как свой exitstatus?

Comment: Ну да, если нужен только status, то pipe не нужен. Меня картинка с PID ввела в заблуждение.

Comment: можно примерчик с кодом?

Comment: Автор, попробуйте пока  сами. Если не получится, то завтра напишу. Идея же такая `while (n) if (fork()) break; if (!--n) { // last child ... exit(rand()); } ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надеюсь, Вы уже сами успешно решили свою задачку, но на всякий случай вот простой код.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>    

int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int n = 5, s;
  srand(getpid());

  while (n--) 
    if (fork())
      break;

  if (n < 0) { // last child
    s = rand() % 100;
    printf("child  %d exit rc: %d\n", (int)getpid(), s);
    exit(s);
  }

  wait(&s);
  if (n != 4) // all except first
    exit(WEXITSTATUS(s));

  printf("Grandfather %d: child exited: %d\n", (int)getpid(), WEXITSTATUS(s));

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Т.е. делаем цикл по переменной (в коде -- `n`), которая наследуется новым процессом и в нем запускаем новый процесс. Родитель выходит из цикла, ждет завершения потомка (тот в свою очередь ждет завершения своего потомка и так 5 раз). Если это не прародитель (определяем по `n`), то выходим с кодом завершения потомка, который получили в `wait()`.

(без pipe передать PID последнего процесса в первый не получится (конечно, кроме разделяемой памяти или файла), но это мы с Вами вроде уже обсуждали).